# How to debug and deploy Legacy solutions

Tags: solution-package, visual-studio-2013

I've migrated from visual Studio 2008 / 2010 + WSP builder for a while now, and have been using Visual Studio 2012 / 2013 + F5.

Now I've come across some legacy solutions, which are still active and now broke. The visual studio solution to this was upgraded and can still be built, but it outputs a dll instead of an wsp package, and therefor can't be debugged like a modern SharePoint solution.

If I hit F5, VS greets me with:

> A Project with an outut type of class library can not be started directly [...]

Is there a (painless) way to pull this legacy code into a modern SharePoint solution, so it is debuggable and deployable from within SharePoint again?

/note: I have installed CKS Dev for Visual Studio 2013 , but can't access them in my solution. They don't seem to be activated (for this project(?)).